# How to remove artifacts at the edge of a GIF?

Tags: animation, gif, anti-aliasing, visual-artifacts

[image]

Open this image in Mozilla or Chrome browser, So you show the display some white pixels in the outer side of gif.
I didn't apply any effect, just used two flat colors and round or text in that.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: You can not. Gif does not have an alpha channel so if your image has antialiasation then thats it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use antialias in transparent GIF images since it's only 8-bit, but you can fake it. When exporting using "Save for Web" use the option **Matte** to match the background color of where the animation will be placed. It adds a few extra colored pixels at the edges of the image.

The downside is that you can only match one color, so it won't work well on top of gradients or a background with a different color.

Comment: Thank your for answer and matte option is work for that because my background color is single color so that's why Matte option is useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after trying to make a GIF for Giphy and the solution I found was changing the Matte option at the export to **none** now my GIF has no outside halo.